# Can't find equivalent of 'docker node ps' in Docker Python SDK

Tags: python, docker, sdk

I'm using the official Docker SDK for Python and i don't find an equivalent for the command :

```
docker node ps <machine_name>
```

Does it exists ?

I'd like to know if there is a way to display each tasks running on a node without having to get each tasks per service using a filter on node and build a list from results.

---

EDIT :

In my case i wanted to get NAME column of 'docker node ps' command.

With the following code i'm getting the service name of every task running on a specific machine (so NAME column without index to make difference between replicas)

```
client = docker.from_env()

def dockerNodePs(machine_name):
    return [s.attrs['Spec']['Name'] for s in client.services.list()
        for _ in s.tasks({'node': machine_name, 
                          'desired-state': 'Running'})]
```

It doesn't match with 'docker node ps' result but it's almost what i needed. So I post it in order to help other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does, here's a [link to the documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nodes.html).

use the following to get all the manager nodes...

```
client.nodes.list(filters={'role': 'manager'})
```

Comment: Your answer match with 'docker node ls' command, not 'docker node ps <machine>'.

My goal is to get tasks running on specific node, not the list of node.